# Get User Specified System Short Time Format (Not System Culture)

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datetimepicker, datetime-format

UPDATE: The culture for the system was being **hardcoded** in another part of the application which is why I was getting the correct but wrong results.

---

I would like to get the system's short time format which can be different than the system's culture's short time format.

I need to apply the system's short time format to a `DateTimePicker` control in Winforms.

Currently, this is the code that I have which gives me the system culture short time which is **not** what I want:

```
// `CurrentCulture` returns "{en-US}"
// `ShortTimePattern` returns "h:mm tt"
dtpTime.CustomFormat = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern;
dtpTime.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

As an example, my system is set to **US culture** but my system short time is set to **24 hour** format. How can I get the system's short time instead of the system culture short time?

Any help or direction on this would be appreciated.

---

A user can modify their date and time formats by going to `Start` **>>** `Date & Time Settings` **>>** `Date, Time, & Regional Formatting` **>>** `Change Data Format`

[image]

Note that the short time is set to 24 hour format.

Comment: I'd suggest adding screenshots showing where in your OS you have set the culture and the system short time since it may make the issue easier to visualise.

Comment: Please also share in your question what the **current** value of `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern` is, and whether that is what you expect it to be. _Please check it in the `Immediate Window` - don't guess._

Comment: What do you mean by "system format"? There's no such thing.

Comment: @mjwills I added the returned value from `ShortTimePattern` call; The `CurrentCulture` is set to {en-US};

Comment: @Dai I am looking for the user entered/specified short time format. This is a setting that users can modify in their Windows systems;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern` (and `ShortDatePattern`) **will match** your Windows' region Short time and Short date setting.

Here's my computer...

- My `CurrentCulture` is `en-GB` ("English (United Kingdom)") which has a default Short-date pattern of `dd/MM/yyyy` and a default Short-time pattern of `HH:mm`.
- I've overriden the Short-date pattern to `yyyy-MM-dd` and the short-time pattern to `hh:mm tt`. You can see this in the Region control-panel screenshot on the left.
- You can see in the LinqPad window that the `CultureInfo.Currentculture.DateTimeFormat`'s `ShortTimePattern` and `ShortDatePattern` match my current Windows Regional settings.
- If you are using `CurrentCulture` and the formats don't match the Region control panel you might need to restart your application. I don't believe `CurrentCulture` reliably refreshes itself whenever system settings change.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am looking for the user specified short date setting. I will add a screenshot to my question to help explain it.

Comment: @Marwanمروان I have updated my answer showing both `ShortDateFormat` and `ShortTimeFormat`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my response, I should have typed short **time** format;

Comment: @Marwanمروان My answer shows `ShortTimeFormat` **and** `ShortDateFormat`. If you're seeing incorrect values make sure you're using `CurrentCulture` (and not `GetCulture` or `new CultureInfo`) as the other methods don't include user customized formats, and also restart your application in case it's using cached values.

Comment: It is very interesting that it is not working for me, I am using ` System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern` but it is still reflecting my system's {en-US} culture settings.
I have restarted the application multiple times but I am still getting the same results.

Comment: @Marwanمروان Please post a screenshot of your Regional control panel (not the new "Settings app") and a screenshot of Regedit's view of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International`

Comment: After reading through your comments and answer above, I decided to look to see if the culture setting is being overwritten in another part of the code, and it is. So this turns out to be a bigger problem than what I thought it is. Please do not ask me why the culture setting is being hardcoded... Sigh... Sorry...
I will respond as soon as I understand why our application is doing that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Marwanمروان You may wish to edit your question to make that clearer.

Comment: @mjwills Should I delete this question?